# Test failure for Multibit on Windows

Tags: client, multibit, windows

I am trying to compile Multibit on Windows:

```
Windows 7, 
IDEA 13.0.2, 
Maven 3.0, 
Multibit 0.5.16.
```

I am able to compile, but when I try to test there are always 2 failures:

```
Running org.multibit.file.ExportTransactionsSubmitActionTest
11:31:54.896 [main] DEBUG org.multibit.model.BaseModel - Initial view from properties file is 'WELCOME_VIEW' 
11:31:55.671 [main] DEBUG o.m.model.bitcoin.WalletInfoData - The wallet version in the constructor was '3'. In the wallet info file it was '2'. Using the latter. 
11:31:55.678 [main] DEBUG org.multibit.file.FileHandler - rememberFileSizesAndLastModified: Wallet filename C:\Projects\BCColors\multibit-master\.\.\src\test\resources\wallets\protobuf1.wallet , walletFileSize 986 ,walletFileLastModified 1393765318000 ,walletInfoFileSize 688 ,walletInfoFileLastModified 1393765318000 
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.8 sec <<< FAILURE!
testExportTransactions(org.multibit.file.ExportTransactionsSubmitActionTest)  Time elapsed: 0.799 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Row 1 incorrect expected:<29 Jul 2013 1[0]:23,"Sent to ""unenc...> but was:<29 Jul 2013 1[2]:23,"Sent to ""unenc...>
```

and

```
Running org.multibit.viewsystem.swing.action.CreateNewReceivingAddressSubmitActionTest
<......>

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 46.048 sec <<< FAILURE!
testAddReceivingAddressesWithEncryptedWallet(org.multibit.viewsystem.swing.action.CreateNewReceivingAddressSubmitActionTest)  Time elapsed: 46.047 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Wrong number of keys after addition of 20 keys expected:<22> but was:<2>
```

And more common question. **Multibit code is very poorly documented. Does anybody have any reference/tutorial/explanation about it?**

Comment: Sounds like a wallet file / software versions mismatch, do you have an old wallet file on that PC somewhere maybe?

Comment: I first installed 0.5.17 version, then uninstalled it and got 0.5.16 version from github. Seems like there still are some odds and ends of 0.5.17 though. How can I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tests you mention are tests that drive the UI classes directly. They are a bit like robot tests and are a bit fiddly. If you don't run those specific tests you lose a bit of UI test coverage but no coverage of the deeper classes.

RE: the code being poorly documented: There are lots of Java doc comments, pretty much everywhere. You'll appreciate that the documentation effort has been much more on the end user side of things. MultiBit is a fairly typical MVC architecture, though of course it has accumulated a fair amount of cruft over time. Surprisingly code is almost always documented in line.